# Reducing memory foot print in Apache Ignite 2.0

Tags: key-value, ignite, key-value-store

I am using Apache Ignite 2.0 as key-value store.  My key will be 10 to 15 digit number and value is a single integer. I intent to store around 500 million such key-value pairs.

On benchmarking, found that to store 1million such key-value entries, the memory utilisation is around 90MB. To store just an integer as value, I don't want to invest such huge memory. i.e., around 90Bytes per record having single integer as value.

Can someone throw some light on how can I reduce memory overheads used in key. Are there any configurations? As I don't need any compression, can I cut down BinaryObjectImpl which is using 40Bytes or some other meta info?

OR if someone can highlight on other kv-stores or technologies I can explore to store huge number of records (even few billions) with lesser memory foot print would be appreciated.

Update:
I am using example-cache.xml as my configuration which is shipped as is without any changes.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you calculate this size? Have you tried to add one more million key-value pairs and calculate size again?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a key-value store (no data grid) have you tried MapDB? http://www.mapdb.org/

It offers off-heap storage and scales well. We've used it successfully in a couple of projects for cache storage.

Comment: Hi steve, thanks for your reply. I have checked mapdb. I can understand its a limitless java collection.  But how do I scale. I didnt see any clustering feature.